# eslint-disable does not suppress errors for the unicorn/filename-case eslint rule

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a file called

```
payment-shipping.tsx
```

and eslint is throwing an error

```
Filename is not in camel case. Rename it to `paymentShipping.tsx`  unicorn/filename-case
```

However, the file needs to be in kebab case since it's a next.js page that shows up in the URL.

Adding the following line to the top of said file:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line unicorn/filename-case
```

Does not suppress the error, it instead throws another error:

```
'unicorn/filename-case' rule is disabled but never reported        eslint-comments/no-unused-disable
```

How do I suppres the filename-case error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ignore`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/filename-case.md#ignore) option of that rule.

.eslintrc

```
...
rules: {
    ...
    "unicorn/filename-case": [
       "error",
       {
           "case": "kebabCase",
           "ignore": [
               /pages/.*\.js$/
           ]
       }
    ]
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks in my case , specifically `"src/pages/**/*.tsx"` worked. The double asterisk captures all recursive folders..